# Paste while in Overwrite / Insert mode with Sublime Text

Tags: insert, sublimetext2, sublimetext, overwrite, caret

When in Overwrite mode (enabled with <kbd>Insert</kbd> key), if the cursor is on the letter `W`:

```
Hello |World
```

then pasting `123` from clipboard (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) gives:

```
Hello 123World
```

instead of `Hello 123ld`. **How to have this behaviour instead?**

---

Note: Similarly, starting with `Hello Wor|ld`, doing <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> gives `Hello Wld` whereas we could expect (since we're in Overwrite/Insert mode) `Hello W  ld`.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a bug in sublime text, according to me.

In the Sublime Text issue tracker on GitHub, the collaborator suggested that "If it's only for pasting, you can do something about that by writing a plugin that handles pasting the clipboard and removing the appropriate number of characters. Then you just need to override the keybinding to map to your custom command.

The only thing you need to consider is newlines and multiple selections (to replicate ST functionality)."

You can see this issue at https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/346